# why is my android application so slow?

Tags: java, android, performance, lag

I've been following [this](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html) tutorial. I've been playing around with code, taking things out I don't need and adding things etc, but when I run it in the emulator the blocks move in a very stuttery motion. It's like I'm getting a low FPS. For the first second or so of running the application it runs smoothly and then again for about a second when I recompile it before it closes. Any idea how to make it run smoothly all the time?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mobilecoursework;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new Blocks(this));
    }
}
```

blocks.java

```
package com.example.mobilecoursework;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
 import android.view.SurfaceView;


 class Blocks extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    //
    private BlockThread _thread;
    //declare an array of the block sprites 
    private ArrayList<GraphicObject> _graphics = new ArrayList<GraphicObject>();


    public Blocks(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        _thread = new BlockThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }



    public void DrawBlocks(){
        for (int i=0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            //create new random x and y position values
            Random randX = new Random();
            int i1=randX.nextInt(getWidth()-0) + 0;
            Random randY = new Random();
            int i2=randY.nextInt(getHeight()-0) + 0;
            GraphicObject graphic = new GraphicObject(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.block));
            graphic.getCoordinates().setX((int) i1 - graphic.getGraphic().getWidth() / 2);
            graphic.getCoordinates().setY((int) i2 - graphic.getGraphic().getWidth() / 2);
            _graphics.add(graphic);
        }
    }

    public void updatePhysics() {
        GraphicObject.Coordinates coord;
        for (GraphicObject graphic : _graphics) {
            //move blocks down
            coord = graphic.getCoordinates();
            coord.setY(coord.getY() + 5 );                
            // reset block
            if (coord.getY() + graphic.getGraphic().getHeight() > getHeight()+10) {
                coord.setY(-10);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        Bitmap bitmap;
        GraphicObject.Coordinates coords;
        for (GraphicObject graphic : _graphics) {
            bitmap = graphic.getGraphic();
            coords = graphic.getCoordinates();
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, coords.getX(), coords.getY(), null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        _thread.setRunning(true);
        _thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // simply copied from sample application LunarLander:
        // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or else
        // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
        boolean retry = true;
        _thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                _thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }
    }
}

class BlockThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private Blocks _Blocks;
    private boolean _run = false;

    public BlockThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Blocks blocks) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        _Blocks = blocks;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }

    public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
        return _surfaceHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        _Blocks.DrawBlocks();

        while (_run) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                    _Blocks.updatePhysics();
                    _Blocks.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class GraphicObject {
    //
     // Contains the coordinates of the graphic.
     //
    public class Coordinates {
        private int _x = 100;
        private int _y = 0;

        public int getX() {
            return _x + _bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        }

        public void setX(int value) {
            _x = value - _bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return _y + _bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
        }

        public void setY(int value) {
            _y = value - _bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Coordinates: (" + _x + "/" + _y + ")";
        }
    }

    private Bitmap _bitmap;
    private Coordinates _coordinates;


    public GraphicObject(Bitmap bitmap) {
        _bitmap = bitmap;
        _coordinates = new Coordinates();

    }

    public Bitmap getGraphic() {
        return _bitmap;
    }



    public Coordinates getCoordinates() {
        return _coordinates;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested on a real device?

Comment: [Do I look like a Guru?](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Guru_Myth)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The emulator is terribly slow and probably the cause of your issues.  Nothing jumps out of your code, so try it on a real device before you tear your hair out trying to make it smoother.

Comment: +1,000. Never trust the emulator to give you real world performance.